# Hadoop Balancer fails with - IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams (LeaseRenewer Warning)

Tags: hadoop

I am stumbling across this error while running the Hadoop Balancer via Namenode. Anytips on cracking this. The process is also blocking the current user and giving an Out of Memory error on issuing any other command.

```
   14/05/09 11:30:05 WARN hdfs.LeaseRenewer: Failed to renew lease for [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-77290934_1] for 936 seconds.  Will retry shortly ...

 java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams; Host Details : local host is: "hadoop01.xx.xx.xx.xx.com/30.0.1.176"; destination host is: "hadoop01.xx.xx.xx.xx.com":8022; 
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:763)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:202)
        at $Proxy10.renewLease(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:83)
        at $Proxy10.renewLease(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.renewLease(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:458)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.renewLease(DFSClient.java:649)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.renew(LeaseRenewer.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.run(LeaseRenewer.java:442)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.access$700(LeaseRenewer.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer$1.run(LeaseRenewer.java:298)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:671)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2100(Client.java:252)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1291)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1209)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
        at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:640)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:664)
        ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the number of threads created by Hadoop RPC reaches the (ulimit -u) on the node's number of processes, java will report it as an out-of-memory error.

Try increasing the maximum number of processes allowed, i.e. your ulimit -u value.